# Changing Line types within the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

New to R, and using ggplot with data. I want to make the black line dashed and the colored one smooth rather than both smooth. How do I separate the two?

```
ggplot(ctwo, aes(x =Scale.Size, y = Pattern.Energy)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(color=Distance), se = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("control" = "black", "2cm" = "#a8ddb5")) +
  labs(x="Scale Size", y = "Pattern Energy") +
  theme_classic()
```

when I add the geom_line it swaps both to dashed.

Comment: You can look into `linetype` in `geom_line(aes(linetype = ))`

Comment: Change `geom_smooth(aes(color=Distance), se = FALSE) +` to `geom_smooth(aes(color=Distance, color = Distance), se = FALSE) +` and add the line `scale_linetype_manual(values = c("control" = 2, "2cm" = 1) +` before your line starting with `labs`. For future questions please add a [mre] so that users can provide a demonstration of the answer on your own data. Welcome to Stack Overflow!